# golang syscall, locked to thread

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I am attempting to create an program to scrape xml files. I'm experimenting with go because of it's goroutines. I have several thousand files, so some type of multiprocessing is almost a necessity...

I got a program to successfully run, and convert xml to csv(as a test, not quite the end result), on a test set of files, but when run with the full set of files, it gives this:

```
runtime: program exceeds 10000-thread limit
```

I've been looking for similar problems, and theres a couple, but i haven't found one that was similar enough to solve this.

and finally heres some code im running:

```
// main func (start threads)

for i := range filelist {
  channels = append(channels, make(chan Test))
  go Parse(files[i], channels[len(channels)-1])
}

// Parse func (individual threads)

func Parse(fileName string, c chan Test) {
defer close(c)

doc := etree.NewDocument()
if err := doc.ReadFromFile(fileName); err != nil {
    return
}

root := doc.SelectElement("trc:TestResultsCollection")

for _, test := range root.FindElements("//trc:TestResults/tr:ResultSet/tr:TestGroup/tr:Test") {
    var outcome Test
    outcome.StepType = test.FindElement("./tr:Extension/ts:TSStepProperties/ts:StepType").Text()
    outcome.Result = test.FindElement("./tr:Outcome").Attr[0].Value
    for _, attr := range test.Attr {
        if attr.Key == "name" {
            outcome.Name = attr.Value
        }
    }

    for _, attr := range test.FindElement("./tr:TestResult/tr:TestData/c:Datum").Attr {
        if attr.Key == "value" {
            outcome.Value = attr.Value
        }
    }

    c <- outcome
}

}

// main (process results when threads return)

for c := 0; c < len(channels); c++ {
    for i := range channels[c] {
        // csv processing with i
    }
}
```

I'm sure theres some ugly code in there. I've just picked up go recently from other languages...so i apologize in advance. anyhow

any ideas?

Comment: That is just part of a the stack trace. What is the actual error?

Comment: runtime: program exceeds 10000-thread limit

Comment: I wasn't aware there was a hard limit?
i didn't see tis till you mentioned it. it scrolled by too fast

Comment: You're going to run out of resources doing this in some way or another. Setting an arbitrarily high limit on system threads seems reasonable. You're definitely not gaining any efficiency by running 10000 threads.

Comment: yeah...any better ideas for 20,000 files?

Comment: Reading this many files concurrently doesn't gain you anything, so limit the number of files you read concurrently.

Comment: Use the usual "limited worker pool for large number of jobs" pattern. See, e.g., https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools (note: choose #workers based on your computer's ability to talk to multiple web sites, which will *probably* correlate to some degree with the number of CPUs you have, but in some non-obvious way, such as "150% of #cpus, or 20, whichever is smaller" for instance).

Comment: that's wonderful. thank you very much :)
so to make sure i understand, i have 4 cores, and 8 logical processors. so it wld be 1.5 x 8 = 12 workers?

Comment: I have one more question, but i guess the proper thing to do is mark this as complete and create a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for not including the correct error.
as the comments pointed out i was doing something dumb and creating a routine for every file. Thanks to JimB for correcting me, and torek for providing a solution and this link.
https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

```
jobs := make(chan string, numJobs)
results := make(chan []Test, numJobs)

for w := 0; w < numWorkers; w++ {
    go Worker(w, jobs, results)
    wg.Add(1)
}

// give workers jobs

for _, i := range files {
    if filepath.Ext(i) == ".xml" {
        jobs <- ("Path to files" + i)
    }
}

close(jobs)
wg.Wait()

//result processing <- results
```